# Obj C - populate TableView with objects at specific indexes in array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I want to populate my TableView with objects from my array at specific indexes. I thought I could do this by looping an `insertObject` line and adding the objects that I want to populate the TableView with (at the specific indexes) to a new array and then populating the tableView with the new array but at the end the new array is nil.

The first array is layout like this: email, name, key code, email, name, key code, email, name, key code, etc...... So i want to fill the second array with just the keycodes and then use the key code array and fill the table with it

This is what I have so far:

.h

```
@property(nonatomic) NSArray *productList;
@property(nonatomic) NSMutableArray *productKeycodes;
```

.m

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
// If You have only one(1) section, return 1, otherwise you must handle sections
return 1;
}




- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
 {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.productList count] / 3;
 }





- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}



self.productKeycodes = [NSMutableArray new];

bool flag = true;
int index = 3;
int arraySize = [self.productList count];
int numberOfKeycodes = [self.productList count] / 3;

while (flag) {

    self.productKeycodes = [self.productList objectAtIndex: index];

    //[self.productKeycodes insertObject: self.productList atIndex: index];

    if (arraySize > numberOfKeycodes) {
        index = index + 3;
        arraySize = arraySize - 3;
    }else{
        flag = false;
    }
}


cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[self.productKeycodes objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}
```

Breakpoint data after loop is done:

```
self    ProductListViewController * 0x7a2831c0
UIViewController    UIViewController    
_productListTableView   UITableView *   0x7b30c400
_productList    __NSArrayM *    @"49 elements"  0x78ebe380
_productKeycodes    NSMutableArray *    nil 0x00000000
numberOfKeycodes    int 16
index   int 26
arraySize   int 13
flag    bool    true
```

At get a `signal SIGABRT` error here:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
//The line below
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));//Here!
//The line above
    }
}
```

**is my logic wrong and/or is there a better way to do this? Thanks!**

Comment: let me know if you need furthur help

Comment: if (arraySize <= numberOfKeycodes) - always false!!!

Comment: updated my code, i say this earlier and didnt update the question

Comment: if (arraySize > numberOfKeycodes) - always true )

Comment: while loop never finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace all code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier]; 
    if (cell == nil) { 
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]; 
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = self.productList[indexPath.row * 3 + 2];
    return cell;
}
//
```

Comment: the app crashes before i get to the table view

Comment: you can't get table while you don't prepare correct array for it

Comment: the array type shouldn't be the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120893/discussion-between-igor-and-lazar-k).

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong.

When you want to add something to the table view you need to do it as follows:

1. Update you data source i.e. `productList` in your case.
2. When you are finished updating the data source, call `self.tableView.relaodData()`

That is all you need to do to insert data to UITableView

Comment: My array isnt being filled which is why its giving me the error i belive, so i want to figure that out. Plus that code didnt work

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to do this

Why do you divide count by 3 and mess with index and flags?

It's ok if you have a good reason but the code to populate your `tableview` should not belong in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

It is not so clear what you are trying to achieve but the correct way is to update your data source and reload the `tableView`.

Comment: I divide by three because the array is set with items that cover 3 spots (email, name, keycode) so the array would be email, name, keycode, email, name, keycode, email, name, keycode, email, name, keycode, email, etc...... So to grab just the keycodes and fill the TableView with that i just need to take the original array and divide by 3

Comment: it sounds like your data is not well structured, you should have an array of dictionaries where each dictionary contains email name.

Comment: it makes sense later in the app but getting the Table View to populate with just the keycodes is exactly what i want

Comment: well I know what you want but you are not doing it correctly at least you should reload the table , also if the array is nil it means you never initialized it

Comment: i get the crash when i try to load the table view with the nil array, so i dont have nothing to reload and i initialized it, still have the problem

Comment: you need to troubleshoot it, Nslog or debug will help u

Comment: after doing so i figured it out! thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You can create an array of your desired indexes. then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. get the data this way:

```
int data = datas[indexes[indexPath.row]];
```

I hope you get the idea

Comment: where do i put the code? also i dont think the issue is that the index is wrong, my second array is nil